# Is there a more generics-y way to do this type of behavior?

Tags: c#, generics

We do a lot of packing and unpacking from `DataRow`.  Yes, we should be using an ORM, but until then, this is what we've got.  As a result of this, there is a lot of code that looks like this:

```
string username;

var temp = dr["Username"];
if (DbNull.Equals (temp))
{
    username = "Anonymous";
} else {
    username = dr["Username"].ToString();
}
```

Eventually, this became a pattern and was translated into helper methods:

```
string username = StringExtensions.SafeParse (dr["Username"], "Anonymous");
```

This is still cumbersome, and required extension methods for all kinds of primitives.  It also clutters up the code.  I created a generic extension method, on `object`, called `As<T>`.  Usage looks like:

```
string username = dr["Username"].As<string> ("Anonymous");
```

This relatively simple change has been met with great aplomb with the other developers, and is getting used in a LOT of places.  The part I'm unhappy with are potential performance implications.  **Now, I'm aware of no premature optimization**.  I definitely wrote the code without any premature optimization, and it's encapsulated enough that optimizing it afterwards shouldn't be a big deal.  I've benchmarked the method to do about two and a half million conversions per second on my relatively modest 2GHz workstation, and I must admit this is phenomenal performance, compared to the time it saves other devs and the readability boost we gain.  However, given the sample of code below, I feel like I'm misusing language features and it could be done much better.  The method is xmldoc'ed with "HERE BE DRAGONS" for crying out loud!  I'm looking for a better way to avoid the double-boxing.  The actual version, which I've omitted for brevity, actually uses `TryParse` in many instances.

```
public static TDestination As<TDestination> (this object source, TDestination defaultValue = default(TDestination))
{
    if (source is TDestination)
        return (TDestination) source;

    if (source == null || DbNull.Equals(source))
        return defaultValue;

    if (TDestination is int)
        return (TDestination) (object) Convert.ToInt32 (source.ToString ());

    if (TDestination is long)
        return (TDestination) (object) Convert.ToInt64 (source.ToString ());

    if (TDestination is short)
        return (TDestination) (object) Convert.ToInt16 (source.ToString ());

    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Your `As<TDestination>` code sample does not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not check if your object is IConvertible, and, if it is, use ToType:

```
var convertible = source as IConvertible;
if (convertible != null)
    return (TDestination)convertible.ToType(typeof(TDestination), Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the example `As` method given in your question, you could just do this instead:

```
public static TDestination As<TDestination>
    (this object source, TDestination defaultValue = default(TDestination))
{
    if ((source == null) || Convert.IsDBNull(source))
        return defaultValue;

    return (TDestination)source;
}
```

Comment: Does a straight cast like that do any conversion behavior or does it just rely on implicit casting?

Comment: @insta: No, it doesn't. But your own `As` method does an `if (source is int)` check before calling `Convert.ToInt32`, and does an `if (source is long)` check before calling `Convert.ToInt64`, etc. If you already know that `source` is a boxed `int` then calling `ToString` followed by `Convert.ToInt32` followed by a boxing cast to `object` just gives you exactly what you started with -- a boxed `int` -- which you then cast to `TDestination`. (Similarly with `long`, `short` etc.) So why not just avoid the pointless round-trip and cast to `TDestination` directly?

Comment: oh christ it's because I screwed up the question.  My code actually checks typeof(TDestination) not source, which changes the game a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever i goes into reflection or checking the `T` of my generic class i'm going to use a dictionary `Dictionary<Type, ???>`. As value i always put something in that should be done for each time as `Func` or `Action`. In your case i would write it maybe in that way:

```
public static class MyConverter
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> _MyConverter;

    static MyConverter()
    {
        _MyConverter = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();

        // Use the Add() method to include a lambda with the proper signature.
        _MyConverter.Add(typeof(int), (source) => Convert.ToInt32 (source.ToString()));

        // Use the index operator to include a lambda with the proper signature.
        _MyConverter[typeof(double)] = (source) => Convert.ToDouble(source.ToString());

        // Use the Add() method to include a more complex lambda using curly braces.
        _MyConverter.Add(typeof(decimal), (source) =>
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(source.ToString());
        });

        // Use the index operator to include a function with the proper signature.
        _MyConverter[typeof(float)] = MySpecialConverterFunctionForFloat;
    }

    // A function that does some more complex conversion which is simply unreadable as lambda.
    private static object MySpecialConverterFunctionForFloat(object source)
    {
        var something = source as float?;

        if (something != null
            && something.HasValue)
        {
            return something.Value;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static TDestination As<TDestination>(this object source, TDestination defaultValue = default(TDestination))
    {
        // Do some parameter checking (if needed).
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        // The fast-path exit.
        if (source.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TDestination)))
            return (TDestination)source;

        Func<object, object> func;

        // Check if a converter is available.
        if (_MyConverter.TryGetValue(typeof(TDestination), out func))
        {
            // Call it and return the result.
            return (TDestination)func(source);
        }

        // Nothing found, so return the wished default.
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

The only drawback of this approach that the usage of `object` leads to (un)boxing which maybe makes some performance problems if the function is called repeatedly for often in a very short time. But as always *measure before claiming*.

On the other side it is quite easy to add further converter and you'll be always O(1) due to the usage of the dictionary.

Comment: This looks awesome.  Do you have access to Visual Studio to test it?  I've found problems with the constructor, as it doesn't know about `TDestination` then.  Moving the dictionary initialization into the `As` method itself seems to defeat the purpose of caching :(

Answer (score 0):

How about defining an extension method for the datarow Field property where you can supply your own null value of the same type as the Field, like so:

```
        public static T Field<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName, T nullValue) { return !row.IsNull(columnName) ? row.Field<T>(columnName) : nullValue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that making a variation of the Field function is the best way to go, but if you are concerned about performance then don't use IsNull() or the actual Field function as these perform a lot of redundant checking. The following method is all you really need.

```
public static T Field<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName, T nullValue)
{
  object value = row[columnName];
  return ((DBNull.Value == value) ? nullValue : (T)value);
}
```

This removes the need for additional boxing to occur and if you're careful with how you use the nullValue parameter you could generally forego having to specify T explicitly when calling the function. win-win.

Comment: The extension method isn't specific to DataRow though, that's just the most common usage of it.  We also use it as a general-purpose casting and data-conversion method.

Comment: In that case, the static constructor method mentioned previously is your most flexible solution. But it comes at quite the price. If you are truly concerned with performance you should consider making specialized AS functions like the one I've provided for your most common cases. This way they can be as optimized as possible.